# Mulitprocessing queue termination

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a program i want to split into 10 parts with multiprocessing. Each worker will be searching for the same answer using different variables to look for it (in this case its brute forcing a password). How to I get the processes to communicate their status, and how do I terminate all processes once one process has found the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to split it into 10 parts than either you should have 10 cores or at least your worker function should not be 100% CPU bound.

The following code initializes each process with a `multiprocess.Queue` instance to which the worker function will write its result. The main process waits for the first entry written to the queue and then terminates all pool processes. For this demo, the worker function is passed arguments 1, 2, 3, ... 10 and then sleeps for that amount of time and returns the argument passed. So we would expect that the worker function that was passed the argument value of 1 to complete first and that the total running time of the program should be slightly more than 1 second (it takes some time to create the 10 processes):

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def init_pool(q):
    global queue
    queue = q

def worker(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    # write result to queue
    queue.put_nowait(x)


def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(queue,))
    for i in range(1, 11):
        # non-blocking:
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,))
    # wait for first result
    result = queue.get()
    pool.terminate() # kill all tasks
    print('Result: ', result)

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    main()
    print('total time =', time.time() - t)
```

Prints:

```
Result:  1
total time = 1.2548246383666992
```